# JRuby on rails framework web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I need more information about the Jruby on rails framework. I have read a lot about the difference between ruby/ruby on rails/jruby/jruby on rails and still do not know fundamental things like:

- is this server side or client side;
- if I use jruby on rails, will be able to use for example jquryUI
- not able to find a clear exmaple of the steps of website development
- if not client side language/which one is good for use with DB2

Note: I have used till now only T-SQL,classic ASP(server side), javacript and jquery(client side). I have done only few desctop applications in Java and mySQL and that's why I need a litle bit more information about jruby on rails before i dive into the books i have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's server side
- As mentioned above it's server side, so jQueryUI can be used without confilict
- Create model, create controller, create view, FIN

Comment: thank you a lot. Could you provide a litle bit more information about the model->controller->view->FIN part?

And just for more information - can you tell me some of its benefits versus other server side languages like asp and php?